# Using a WPF style from another assembly

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have been googling for hours trying out different solutions to my problem but have not been able to find one there or on here.

I have a WPF Custom Control Library that also includes a theme .xaml file that has styles I want to apply to controls, however after linking it as a ResourceDictionary I am unable to access the style when modifying the style attribute of a control.

This is how I am linking it

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MADEV.WPFNotification;component/Themes/Dark.xaml"/>
```

and this is the .xaml file content:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MADEV.WPFNotification">

<SolidColorBrush  x:Key="BG"
                  Color="#FF464646" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="BG_Darker"
                 Color="#FF3A3A3A" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="FG"
                 Color="#FFC5C5C5" />

<Style x:Key="NotificationStyle"
       TargetType="Window">
    <Setter Property="Height"
            Value="36" />
    <Setter Property="Width"
            Value="150" />
    <Setter Property="ResizeMode"
            Value="NoResize" />
    <Setter Property="ShowInTaskbar"
            Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="Topmost"
            Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="Focusable"
            Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop"
            Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="WindowStyle"
            Value="None" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground"
            Value="White" />
    <Setter Property="Background"
            Value="{StaticResource BG}" />
    <Setter Property="AllowsTransparency"
            Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible"
            Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="ShowActivated"
            Value="False" />
</Style>
```

I would appreciate some help with this

Edit 1: Current App.xaml after vesan's answer, yet still not working:

```
<Application x:Class="SimpleOSD.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SimpleOSD"
         xmlns:properties="clr-namespace:SimpleOSD.Properties"
         StartupUri="BackgroundProcess.xaml">
<Application.Resources>
    <properties:Settings x:Key="Settings" />

    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Pack://application:,,,/MADEV.WPFNotification;component/Themes/Dark.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Comment: +1 to counter the anonymous down-vote with no explanation you received before (because I find those to be rude and unhelpful for anyone trying to learn) but give "merged resource dictionaries wpf" a google and you'll find your answer pretty quickly in one of the many tutorials. Cheers

Comment: Thanks Chris, that is exactly what I have done before, but sadly none of the solutions I found that had worked for others have worked for me.

Comment: I posted a very basic solution below. If that doesn't work for you, I would suggest starting with an empty project and adding your stuff back in. Also, when debugging, watch the Output window for WPF errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to move `<properties:Settings x:key=Settings>` inside `<ResourceDictionary>` tag.Since, Application.Resources requires an instance of ResourceDictionary.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to have partially fixed it, but now I get `Assembly 'MADEV.WPFNotification' is not referenced by this project` even though it has definitely been added to the references, any idea?

Comment: Found my mistake, forgot changing the assembly name in the project properties, it is working now, thanks!

Answer (score 10):

OK, I'll just post the most basic implementation, which will hopefully show you the right direction.

First the control library, project WpfControlLibrary1, file Dictionary1.xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TestBrush" Color="LightBlue"></SolidColorBrush>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Now the WPF application, WpfApplication1 (references the control library), file App.xaml:

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApplication1.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/WpfControlLibrary1;component/Dictionary1.xaml"></ResourceDictionary>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

And finally, Window1.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Window1" Height="400" Width="600" 
        Background="{StaticResource TestBrush}">
</Window>
```

Referencing the resource dictionary in App.xaml will make it available to all windows/controls in your WPF application. If you don't want that, you can move the code from App.xaml to a specific XAML file.

And here's the result:

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering, however I have tried this before but this throws the "Each dictionary entry must have an associated key" error at me and still doesn't let me access the style.

Comment: Have you checked that everything in your dictionary has an `x:Key` attribute? When referencing the dictionary, have you made sure that it's inside `ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries` and not directly under the `ResourceDictionary`?

Comment: Yes I did, I have updated the question to show you, the `ResourceDictionary` doesn't  need one right?

Answer (score 4):

I know it's a long time since this question was asked, but I recently needed find out of this and ended up here. So I thought I should share my solution as well.

Lets say that you have two assemblies (in same solution).

1. MyProject1
2. MyProject1.UI

**Step 1.** 
Make sure that your are referencing the MyProject1.UI in MyProject1.

MyProject1-> References -> Add Reference... -> Projects -> MyProject1.UI

**Step 2.**
Then in MyProject1.UI you have a folder called "Styles" with this Brush.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="NormalBackgroundBrush" Color="SteelBlue"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ErrorBackgroundBrush" Color="LightCoral"/>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

**Step 3.**
Then you edit your App.xaml in MyProject1 from this:

```
<Application x:Class="MyProject1.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles/Brushes.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

To this:

```
<Application x:Class="MyProject1.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/MyProject1.UI;component/Styles/Brushes.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

**Step 4.**
Now you can use the brushes as *StaticResource* in your MyProject1.UI like this:

```
Background="{StaticResource NormalBackgroundBrush}"
```

or

```
Background="{StaticResource ErrorBackgroundBrush}"
```

Hope it helps someone : )